# How to display posts on a news page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can easily do it if i make a custom post but doing so will make the original post type unused. I would like to use it than building a new custom post type. I have made page-news.php   but it is not able to show up on this page. also Currently, post are showing up 
www.somedomain.com/posts_title format  i would like it to be www.somedomain.com/news/posts_title

**here is my page.news.php**

```
<?php 
/*
  Template Name: News
*/
?>
<?php get_header();?>
<div class="mainwrapper">
<!-- slide -->
</div>

<div class="content content-topone">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row portfolio">
            <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => '', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfoliobox">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php 
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } else {
                        $img = '/img/responsive-webness.png"';
                       $attrib = ' class="' . 'img-responsive' . '" alt="' . ' '. '"/>';
                       $begin = '<img src="';
                       $getpath = get_template_directory_uri();
                        echo $begin . $getpath. $img . $attrib;
                      }
                    ?>
                    </a>

                    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
          </div>
          <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
          <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
    </div>     
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => '', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

To this:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

So you can display native `posts` in your news page. All you need to do just loop

```
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        ?><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><?php
    }
}
```

To display any custom post type just change the `post_type` in the array. Read more [on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

To change the `URI` format, go to your `WordPress` dashboard and then navigate to  `Settings->Permalink` from menu and then select the `Custom Structure` radio button and enter `/%postname%/%category%/` in the text box and then save the changes. [Check this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for more.

[image]

Comment: $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => '', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );  works to display. It does same as $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); because it is built-in default post type.

Comment: Then what is your question/problem with this ?

Comment: It is not able to get page-news.php for templating, and display url like this www.somedomain.com/news/posts_title  news is the page i created. I want to display posts on news.

Comment: In this case you need to create a [custom template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and I have already answered how you can change the `url` format.